# Power BI -- how to create the desired table for use in a bar chart?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm pretty new at Power BI (so forgive my rough terminology), and I'm trying to create a bar chart from some existing financial data.  Specifically, I'd like to know how to transform my data.  I've looked at DAX and python, and can't quite figure out the right commands.

My existing table looks like the following.  The set of categories are arbitrary (not known up front, so can't be hardcoded), same with the set of years.

```
Category  2002  2003  2004  2005
A         $10   $75   $75   $75 
B         $75   $59   $75   $79 
C         $15   $32   $13   $5 
B         $23   $12   $75   $7 
C         $17   $88   $75   $15
```

And I want my output table to have the number of rows as the number of *unique* categories, totaling up the dollar amounts for each year.

```
Category  2002  2003  2004  2005
A         $10   $75   $75   $75 
B         $98   $71   $150  $86
C         $32   $120  $88   $20
```

What's the best way to roll up the data this way?  I intend to use the resulting table to make a composite bar chart, one bar per year.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Avoid Excel-style cross-tables in Power BI. In the PowerQuery Editor transform your table by selecting Categorie and then **Unpivot other columns**

[image]

2. Back in the designer view you can directly use this data to create a bar chart:

[image]

3. If you like you can also create an aggregated table from your data with the **calculated table** expression

```
Aggregated = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Table',
    'Table'[Category],
    'Table'[Year],
    "Sum", SUM('Table'[Value])
)
```

but that's not needed for your purpose.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!  I learned an incredible amount from that...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full M-Code to achieve your goal: Just change the source step with your source file:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUTI0ABLmpkhErE60khOMb2oJl7EEyziD9ID4xkYgljFIDVyLEYhraATXgtBhDiQsLGASQANiYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Category = _t, #"2002" = _t, #"2003" = _t, #"2004" = _t, #"2005" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Category", type text}, {"2002", Int64.Type}, {"2003", Int64.Type}, {"2004", Int64.Type}, {"2005", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Category"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", "Year"}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"Category", "Year"}, {{"Total", each List.Sum([Value]), type number}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[Year]), "Year", "Total", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

If we test it:
[image: GG_Editor]